# How to completly turn off git line endings auto correction

Tags: git, git-svn, gitattributes

I'm writing a script that migrates our SVN repos to GIT. I have discovered that one repo contains a `.gitattributes` file (with content like `* type=text`). That unfortunately means that all files are modified (line endings are auto corrected).

I don't want that because as a next step we are doing branch filtering (using `git filter-branch`) and it can't proceed with unstaged changes/uncommitted changes (and I also don't want to commit them).

How can I avoid changing endline characters on migration?

Comment: Probably a better idea to use a bare checkout

Comment: Delete the `.gitattributes`?

Comment: Unfortunately some developer added whole library downloaded from somewhere and it contained the .gitattributes file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete the `.gitattributes` file and do migration.

After you do it, set up the [`.gitattributes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) and/or [`git config core.autocrlf`](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config) on your working machine(s) in the proper way.

I've asked that in comments and still interested: Why could your SVN repo contain a `.gitattributes` file? For what purpose was it added to an SVN repo?